# Model field not found in ContentType model

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models

In my local pc, there is a file located at **usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-package/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py** which contains model named 'ContentType'. This model contains three fields:

```
class ContentType(models.Model):
    app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    model = models.CharField(_('python model class name'), max_length=100)
    objects = ContentTypeManager()
```

Again there is another file located at **usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-package/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py** which contains model named 'ContentType'. This model contains four fields:

```
class ContentType(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
app_label = models.CharField(max_length=100)
model = models.CharField(_('python model class name'), max_length=100)
objects = ContentTypeManager()
```

I am using django==1.8.7 version
In my project I am getting the 'ContentType' model with 3 fields(first one) where as I need to get access to 'ContentType' model with 4 fields(second one).

Can you explain me why I am facing this and please give me a solution.

Comment: Wherever you're trying to use it, you're importing the wrong one.

Comment: Dear @Sayse, can you please explain me what you commented in answer?

Comment: The two file paths in your question are exactly the same.

Comment: It wasn't an answer per say, but you are "getting" the one with 3 fields because that is the one you are referencing.